# query takes longer time to execute even if index are created

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-performance

I have table `DB_TBL` where historical data are inserted from tool on 5th of every month. As its historical data the number of rows inserted is very large. For example i checked the count for this month and its 1626521.

This table contains 50 columns. But i am interested to check only 5 columns. There is gui from the front end which is using this 5 columns and where i am providing the filter to get the one month data everytime for example for previous month as closure_date between 01.01.2020 and 31.01.2020.

```
Select Client_key, Portfolia_Name, Closure_date, 
    Currency_Type, Balance from DB_TBL        
    where CLOSURE_DATE between 
    to_date ('01.01.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date ('31.01.2020','dd.mm.yyyy');
```

This query is very slow and takes more than 30 minute to run. This problem is very critical as the same issue i faced from the gui. I have provided index to `Closure_date` column. But still it does not improve performance.

Is there any way i can improve query performance ? May be i can create `Virtual based index`  or create `View` ?

Comment: Post your table definition.

Comment: How are you measuring performance? Is that actual query execution time or does it include GUI rendering?

Comment: in both way it takes lot of time..from gui i am creating csv from this data as a part of report

Comment: I meant, have you run this query by itself in a database query tool and checked performance there?

Comment: yes i ran in db visualizer and check the performance

Answer (score 1):

First, I would write the query using date literals:

```
Select Client_key, Portfolia_Name, Closure_date, Currency_Type, Balance
from DB_TBL
where CLOSURE_DATE between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-01-31'
```

For this query, you want an index on `db_tbl(closure_date)`.  If you already have this index, then presumably you have such a large volume of data that it takes a lot of time to return the data.  You can change the index to a covering index by including the rest of the columns in the index (after `CLOSURE_DATE`, which should be first).

That said, if you want all data from January 2020, I would recommend:

```
where CLOSURE_DATE >= date '2020-01-01' and
      CLOSURE_DATE < date '2020-02-01'
```

This will return all rows, even those that have a time component.  This is particularly important in Oracle, because the `date` data type can have a time component -- even though user interfaces often show only the date.

Comment: how can i change the index to covering index ? DO i need to create explictly or change in a query ?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - I'd like to clarify something you said that I know you understand but the OP probably doesn't.  You said "the date data type _can_ have a time component"  (emphasis mine).  I know you understand that the DATE datatype _does have_ (not optional, as implied by "can have") a time component. The only question would be if the time component had a value of zero (midnight) or something else (greater than midnight).

Comment: @EdStevens . . . That is a fair comment.  I tend to think of the "midnight" as the "right" value for something called `date`.  Hence, I equate midnight with a "real" date.  But your interpretation is technically more accurate.

Comment: do you mean composite index to create for whatever the columns i am using in my query ? Also does creating partition helps in this case ?

Comment: @Andrew . .. Partitioning by `CLOSURE_DATE` could possibly help the query.  My guess though is that the limiting issue is the volume of returned data -- unless possibly what you are calling a "table" is really a "view".

Comment: what kind of partitioning might help here do u think i mean an example? the volume will always be huge as its historical table..i can also think of creating view with this 5 columns if it requires and help for optimization